# PWA with Windows Authentication

Tags: .net-core, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, windows-authentication, workbox

On the high level, I have a PWA with React frontend and .netcore backend. I use service worker for caching and offline ability, in conjunction with workbox plugins for some precaching feature.

The app uses Windows Authentication. Which works fine if it wasn't a PWA app. It also works fine the first time the PWA app launches, I get the username, password login popup.

However from the second time visiting the app, it wouldn't show the login popup, the app fails at pulling data from the backend because it is unauthenticated. One weird behavior is that, if I open Chrome Dev Tools(by F12), then the login popup immediately shows up.

I thought it's caching related and somehow the service worker interfered with the server side authentication workflow. Maybe because the index page is cached by the workbox precache plugins, and it did not cache with the fetch header of `'credentials': 'include'`? I tried adding the fetch option to other api routes, which are cached by workbox plugin RegisterRoute. However I didn't find a way to add it to the `precacheAndRoute(self.__WB__MANIFEST)`. Wondering if that's the problem. But I'm also not sure why having Dev Tools open would trigger the popup to display.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a resolution to this? The reason it may have worked with dev tools open is caching was disabled when dev tools is open.